# How to insert IL code call into class type constructor in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, code-injection, mono.cecil, .net-7.0

I have an assembly I want to use and test. Yet I can not change its source code as `.cs` files but I am allowed to change it at runtime (say on app loading). In there I have a class with a public constructor. I want to insert (or inject) a public static function call into it. How to do such thing in .Net?

Comment: Why I can not just edit the code: because it is in a hot loop and so I want to instrument it only in test context. And I do not want to use ifdefs as test cases may change and evolve in a fast manner and I hope to instrument in such a way more than one type

Comment: Seems like some version of this https://github.com/philiplaureano/Deflector.NET could do the job if ported to .net-7 for me

Comment: You already added a tag of Mono Cecil which can help patch the assembly before loading it into AppDomain, so I wonder what kind of answer you are looking for. Maybe you just want someone to write all the code for you like ChatGPT? Then why not use that instead?

Comment: @LexLi - you are right - ChatGPT knows how to write Mono Cecil code. More or less... Wow the age we are living in...